# JS menu animation for website doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added the following JS to my website to add a side menu that slides out from the left and it doesn't work. I am fairly inexperienced with JS so any advice is helpful.

```
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
var main = function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.icon-menu').click(function () {
        $('.menu').animate({
            marginLeft: "150px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            marginLeft: "150px"
        }, 200);
    });

    $('.icon-close').click(function () {
        $('.menu').animate({
            marginLeft: "-150px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

icon-menu and icon-close are both images, icon-menu is on the page and is supposed to reveal the menu which is a div. icon-close is on the menu div.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
        <div class="icon-close">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
        </div>

        <div class="link" id="joinLink"><a href="joinPage.html">Join </a></div>
        <div class="link" id="returnsLink"><a href="returns.html">Returns</a></div>
        <div class="link" id="methodsLink"><a href="methods.html">Methods</a></div>
    </div>
    <img class="icon-menu" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-ui-2/16/UI_Icons_Outline-29-128.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
background-color: white;
left: -150px;
top: 150px;
height: 1000px;
position: fixed;
width: 150px;
}

.icon-close{
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;


}

.icon-menu{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: -320px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: could you share your HTML and CSS also ? so we can help you better

Comment: `It doesn't work` what this means? Have you got errors in console? You need to provide a working example reproducing the issue, not this.

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: For your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/kangrian/WCauA/

Comment: @GopinathShiva that's no a solution. That's another totally different code for the same achievement.

Comment: @Marcos: Yup I just provided him a reference that I believe would help, since OP didn't provide the full code.

Comment: It's fine, sorry if I disturb you :)

Comment: @MihaiT here's the related css and html

Comment: No probs. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any HTML structure from you or CSS , i just made this simple example :

first, with CSS set an inital position for the `.menu` . i used `position:relative` and `left:-150px;` .

then with JQ toggle between `left:0` ( which will show the `.menu` ) and `left:-150px` ( which will hide the `.menu` ) .

i also toggled the buttons so only one is shown at a time.

there are a number of ways to do this but i wanted to change your code as little as possible.

you don't need to style the `body` , just style the `.menu`

**EDIT :** edited snippet with your HTML and CSS ( with modifications )

i suggest you set both `icon-menu` and `icon-close` outside the `.menu` . and also remove the `margin-top` from `.icon-menu`

```js
var main = function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.icon-menu').click(function () {
        $(this).hide()
        $('.icon-close').show()
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0"
        }, 200);

       
    });

    $('.icon-close').click(function () {
        $(this).hide()
         $('.icon-menu').show()
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-150px"
        }, 200);

        
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.menu {
background-color: white;
left: -150px;
top: 40px;
height: 1000px;
position: fixed;
width: 150px;
}

.icon-close{

  height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:none;

}

.icon-menu{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
     

        <div class="link" id="joinLink"><a href="joinPage.html">Join </a></div>
        <div class="link" id="returnsLink"><a href="returns.html">Returns</a></div>
        <div class="link" id="methodsLink"><a href="methods.html">Methods</a></div>
    </div>
    <img class="icon-menu" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-ui-2/16/UI_Icons_Outline-29-128.png"/>

    <img class="icon-close" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png"/>
```

Comment: implemented all of your ideas aside from 'position:relative' as it screws with my formatting, menu still doesn't appear, is this the relative positioning or something else?

Comment: edited my answer with your structure. moved the `icon-close` outside the `.menu` and removed the `margin-top` from `.icon-menu`

Comment: I've put in all of your code but still no success. Not sure what else you can do unless you can find something in your code. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: well in this snippet it works as you want, right ? so maybe you don't have the jquery library installed or some other code is interfering . does your console display any errors ?

Comment: Yeah the snippet works perfectly. I've fixed all the errors it presents, ill check the library but I'm pretty certain that i have it. its probably an error somewhere in my syntax that I'm just going to have to find.